# PHP PEAR Mail and Mail_mime adding attachments to email send with SMTP

Tags: php, email

I am having trouble sending emails with the PHP PEAR Mail and Mail_mime with attachments.

The problem is not sending the email itself the email gets sent just fine its just that the resulting email is a gibberish like mixe of characters.

Here is the content of my test.php(I remove what is not nedded for the question):

```
<?php
//All the custom classes needed for the whole code but I dont use them all for this exemple.
use Framework\cUsager;
use Framework\cConnexion;
use Framework\cPHPMailer;
use Framework\cLog;
use Framework\cFileStream;
use Framework\gConfig as g;

require_once "Config.php";

$HTML = "<div>This is a test</div>";
$Text = "Ceci est un grand grand test";

$mail = new cPHPMailer
(
    'To@exemple.com',
    'From@exemple.com',
    'Test',
    'test.txt',//this is a text file a want to send as attachment, its save in the same directory as test.php
    '1.0',
    'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    $HTML,
    $Text
);

$mail->Mail();
?>
```

And here is the code for cPHPMailer:

```
<?php
namespace Framework;
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

class cPHPMailer
{
//I skipped all the getters and setters as well as the __construct and the attributs you guys can guess that $this->getTo() return to the To attributes in my class.
    public function Mail()
    {
        $header = array
        (
            "To" => $this->getTo(),
            "From" => $this->getFrom(),
            "Subject" => $this->getSubject(),
            "MIME-Version" => $this->getMimeVersion(),
            "Content-Type" => $this->getContentType()
        );

        $mime = new \Mail_mime();

        $mime->setTXTBody($this->getText());
        $mime->setHTMLBody($this->getHTML());

        foreach($this->getAttachments() as $att)
        {
            if($mime->addAttachment($att))
            {
                echo "Att: ".$att."<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "TEST FAILED!!!!!";//THIS IS EDIT #2
            }
        }

        $smtp = \Mail::factory
        (
            'smtp', 
            array
            (
                'host' => gConfig::$SMTPMailHost,//those are store in the Config.php file in test.php (see code above)
                'port' => gConfig::$SMTPMailPort,
                'auth' => gConfig::$SMTPMailAuth,
                'username' => gConfig::$SMTPMailUser,
                'password' => gConfig::$SMTPMailPass
            )
        );

        $envoyer = $smtp->send($this->getTo(),$mime->headers($header),$mime->get());

        echo $envoyer;//this return true/1 meaning that no errors occured
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the content of the email I receive when running the script:

> `--=_88e78c51e29d6b210a754d69484afcbc Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=_2ceac717c96dcbe1a49c37c533389352" --=_2ceac717c96dcbe1a49c37c533389352 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 Ceci est un grand grand test --=_2ceac717c96dcbe1a49c37c533389352 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>   This is a test
>   --=_2ceac717c96dcbe1a49c37c533389352-- --=_88e78c51e29d6b210a754d69484afcbc Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=test.txt Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt Y2VjaSBlc3QgdW4gdGVzdA== --=_88e78c51e29d6b210a754d69484afcbc--`

I was hoping to receive an email with the body either `<div>this is a test</div>` or 'Ceci est un grand grand test' with a text file attach named test.txt.

**EDIT**:
After removing the error suppression operator I received no warning or error.

**EDIT**:
I had a flash, I changed the foreach loop add a If statement to see if the attachment get attach correctly and it does not throw any error it seems to get attach correctly.

results of the echoes:

```
Att: test.txt
1
```

Comment: First step would be to be remove `@` everywhere. Using the error suppression operator is the equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you". But given your sample text, your headers aren't being constructed properly and they're all going on the SAME line of text, which means they're corrupted and won't be interpreted at all by the mail client.

Comment: Going to remove the error suppression operator and get back to you with error message if I have one.

Comment: Done I removed the `@` and posted the result in the EDIT

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line, so probably you've got a dangling `'` somewhere BEFORE the code you've pasted.

Comment: Just saw that this was an old error I already resolved...

Comment: But I am still receiving the gibberish instead of an email that make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happen:

I search the Mail_mime documentation and found this:

**DO NOT EVER TRY TO CALL THESE LINES IN REVERSE ORDER!**

I found it here:(Note by: Paul)

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php

The problem was that `$mime->get();` and `$mime->headers($header);` must be called in this order `get()` first and `Headers()` second.